# NodeJS, Express, PUG - Need to render results from mongo db to variables contained in pug view

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have a site which is used for holding documents and marking entries via a form. I'm currently trying to find all documents within a mongo collection and then use `res.render()` method to populate variables within `documents.pug`.

I tried putting `res.render` within a for loop and then pass `var i` into my results parameter. After some reading, I found out I can't perform `res.render` multiple times(for loop.).

I have a model setup using mongoose. I'm able to find all documents within the collection and return them. My issue here is populating the pug variable I defined via `res.render()` with results returned from `Documents.find({})`(mongoose).

Can anyone perhaps assist me in figuring out a solution for this?

---

document.js

```
module.exports = (app) => {
  // Creating new instance of router for docsPage.
  const docsRouter = require('express').Router();

  // Creating Document const which will contain the documents model schema.
  const Document = require('../models/document.model');

  docsRouter.route('/')

  .get((req, res) => {
    Document.find((err, docs) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        res.send(err);
      }
      else {
        // console.log(docs[0].doc_id);
        res.render('documents', {
          pageTitle: "Documents",
          doc_id: docs.doc_id,
          doc_title: docs.doc_title,
          doc_category: docs.doc_category,
          doc_author: docs.doc_author,
          doc_description: docs.doc_description
        });
      }
    });
  })

  app.use('/documents', docsRouter);
}
```

documents.pug

---

```
extends layout

block main
  div(class="container")
    table(class="uk-table uk-table-striped uk-table-small")
      thead
        tr
          th Document ID
          th Title
          th Category
          th Author
          th Description
      tfoot
      tbody
        - for (var i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
          tr
            td= doc_id
            td= doc_title
            td= doc_category
            td= doc_author
            td= doc_description
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're rendering form with undefined values, because docs is an array, and array won't have Document properties.

Change `res.render` to

```
res.render('documents', {
     pageTitle: "Documents",
     docs: docs
});
```

And Pug view:

```
extends layout

block main
  div(class="container")
    table(class="uk-table uk-table-striped uk-table-small")
      thead
        tr
          th Document ID
          th Title
          th Category
          th Author
          th Description
      tfoot
      tbody
        - each doc in docs
          tr
            td= doc.doc_id
            td= doc.doc_title
            td= doc.doc_category
            td= doc.doc_author
            td= doc.doc_description
```

Comment: Ah geez.... That makes a whole lot more sense. :) I think it's time to step back and think a little more. Thanks very much @hya! That worked like a charm.